# What controls Twitter access rights, when using Fabric.IO and TwitterLogin in Android app?

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter-fabric, access-rights

What controls the Twitter access rights?

1. Is it the Twitter application as defined in my Twitter dev account?
2. Is it the Twitter Android API ?
3. Is it the TwitterLogin plugin info provided by Fabric.IO?
4. Is it a combination of these?
5. Is it something else?

**Using Twitter as a Way to Identify User**

All I want to do is use the Twitter OAuth which is provided by FabricIO and the TwitterLogin infrastructure so I can identify a user.  In other words, let the user sign on using Twitter.  However, I don't need or want more access to their account.

However, as you can see in the image below, the app seems to gain far more access to the user's Twitter account than I need.

**Possible To Change?**

Is it possible to change this so it is very limited?  If so, where would I make those changes?

[image: twitter access rights]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the settings in my twitter dev account and it resolves some of this, but not all.  However, maybe this is all it is even possible to control??

1. Go to https://apps.twitter.com/  (it'll take you to your twitter dev account).
2. If you have more than one app, choose the app you want to change.
3. Click the [Permissions] Tab.
4. You will see something like the following images:

Mine **was** set on **Read & Write** (2nd choice)- Image shows where I have now selected the Read only choice.
[image: choose read only]

Click the [UPdate Settings] button and you get the odd screen that follows:
[image: choice reverts]

That made me think I hadn't chosen the correct choice (read only).

Finally, after a few minutes I refreshed the app settings web page and saw that it was on Read Only.

I then tried logging in using my Android application again and it now looks like the following:
[image]

Now, it cannot tweet for the user nor can it add users.  It still seems a bit intrusive though, just to use it for Authentication.